# WPF Listbox & MVVM binding

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, datacontext, itemssource

I am following MVVM in C# and am attempting to display a view in a listbox.

I am setting the listbox itemsource (in code, not in binding and using the viewmodels collection) and then set the datatemplate to be my view in xaml. The issue I'm encountering is my view always loads with its default constructor values, if I remove the datacontext from the view however it loads fine.

Below is the listbox I am creating in xaml

```
<ListBox Name="lbCatalogues" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <view:CatalogueRowView/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the xaml for my view. If I remove the DataContext it works

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <model:CatalogueModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid Name="Container" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- Catalogue_ID, UploadedTime, Client_ID, Name, Desc, Filesize -->
    <Label Name="lblCatalogueID" Content="{Binding Path=CatalogueID}" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Label Name="lblUploadedTime" Content="{Binding Path=UploadedTime}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Name="lblCatalogueName" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Label Name="lblCatalogueDescription" Content="{Binding Path=Description}" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Label Name="lblFilesize" Content="{Binding Path=Filesize}" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Grid/>
```

This is the code where I am setting the listbox ItemSource:

`lbCatalogues.ItemsSource = catalogueViewModel.Records;`

My question is how can I get the view to load correctly within the listbox so that each item in the listbox has a DataContext linked to that listbox Itemsource?

Answer (score 4):

You already know the answer: simply remove `<UserControl.DataContext>` from your `UserControl`

You are telling your `UserControl` to use a new instance of `CatelogueModel` for the `DataContext`, and this overrides any `DataContext` that is set when you use your `UserControl`. See MSDN's list of [Dependency Property Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) for more info

I do not ever recommend setting the `DataContext` inside a `UserControl`. It goes against how WPF is meant to work by having separate UI and data layers, and is a problem for anyone trying to use your `UserControl`

As for your question about each item in the ListBox linking to the ItemsSource, DataTemplates simply tell WPF how to draw an object. The data behind the object still remains.

For example, your ListBox contains a list of `Record` objects, and your `DataTemplate` is telling the `ListBox` to draw each one of those records with `CatelogueRowView`. The actual data behind the `CatelogRowView` is still your data object from `catelogueViewModel.Records`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in the end I got it working. I got rid of the usercontrol.datacontext. I wanted to use information within the datacontext in the usercontrol_loaded method. I just had to cast the datacontext to get it back (timmeh). I just find it weird that by telling the view its datacontext type it only loads the default constructor rather than loading the model thats being given to it at construction time.

Comment: @user1444261 Your `<UserControl.DataContext>` is not setting the type. Its setting the actual `UserControl.DataContext` property to a new instance of `CatelogueModel`.

Answer (score 0):

> lbCatalogues.ItemsSource = catalogueViewModel.Records; instead of this  Simply bind ItemsSource of ListBox as ItemsSource="{Binding Records}" in xaml. I hope this will help.